# Uniswap V3 estimate ammount out

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, uniswapv3

am using Uniswap V3: Router 2 swapExactTokensForTokens to make simple swaps, eg swap usdc to weth.

The issue am facing is in every and each example found online amountOutMin is defined to 0 , which allows 100% slippage and is not good.

```
encodeFunctionData("swapExactTokensForTokens",[ammount,"0",[token,"0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2"],public_key])
```

I have not found solution for this that would not require me to use uniswap sdk. Which is pointless since am doing this in pure js.

- note ammount is in token native decimal

To do this you need to:

1. Query the right pool from uniswap factory 0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984 , use 1% fee (10000)
2. Query price from the pool using the slot0 function, this returns price
3. price = (sqrtPriceX96 ** 2 / 2 ** 192)
4. min_received = (ammount*(sqrtPriceX96 ** 2 / 2 ** 192))*0.9 (for 10% slippage)

- this should return value in decimals of token you are trying to swap to
  This works but not for tokens with 6 decimals ? huh

Am i missing smt ?

For example in this pool the price should equal 820000000000000wei which is 0.00082 or 1USD at the time

https://etherscan.io/address/0xC5aF84701f98Fa483eCe78aF83F11b6C38ACA71D#readContract

But it equals 1.2235422586602433e-9 or 0.0000000012235422586602433

is this issue in fetching the pool in first place or i need to add decimals calculation

### SOLUTION:

-check token0 in given pool, if it is the currency you want output in, use:

2 ** 192 / sqrtPriceX96 ** 2 * 10 ** (decimals1-decimals0)

-if token 1 is currency you want output in, use:

sqrtPriceX96 ** 2 / 2 ** 192 * 10** (decimals1-decimals0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you read the "sqrtPriceX96" by querying the "slot0" function on the pair contract, then you call the "swap" method on the pair contract. this takes recipient, a true or false which indicated which way you are swapping, the amount, and the "sqrtPriceX96".
It also looks like they have a "Quoter" contract that gives you the amount out for the frontend I assume.

Here are some links to the new interfaces:

pool read fuctions:
https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/core/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolState#slot0

pool write functions:
https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/core/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolActions#swap

quoter functions:
https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/interfaces/IQuoter

Comment: by ammount you mean for example ammount of APE in trade APE to WETH ?
Dont i need to know the price of APE in WETH to calculate amountOutMin?

Comment: Expected ammout out would be
(PRICEINWETH * AMMOUNTOFAPE)*0.99 (for 1 % slippage)
But we still need that price in WETH which i have no clue how to get

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to get the amountOut hope this helps! let me know if you have any questions

Comment: This is exactly what i need but for pancakeswap and bsc.

Comment: Uniswap v2 used to have simmilar approach, no clue what to do on V3 tho

Comment: I see I apologize, I just noticed you said v3. It has certainly changed a lot from v2 looking at  the docs. I'll take a look and try to assist you.

Comment: could you tell me the address of the token you are trying to swap?

Comment: anything to WETH, for example apecoin 0x4d224452801aced8b2f0aebe155379bb5d594381

Comment: I'm a little confused by your previous comment? What you're working on is ETH or BSC?

Comment: Ethereum mainnet

Comment: okay I edited my answer for the last time, hope those links lead you in the right direction my friend!

Comment: Thanks, that helped, am able to get the right slippage for some tokens but cant figure out how to properly set pool fee when querying them from 0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984

Comment: check edit if u can pls

Comment: So I see to query the pool, you have to know the fee ( stupid in my opinion ) BUT in the docs they say this: 

Liquidity providers may initially create pools at three fee levels: 0.05%, 0.30%, and 1%. 

so there are only 3 fee levels to check for: 
1% or 10000 1e-6
.3% or 3000 1e-6
.05% or 500 1e-6

Comment: Yea, figured out 1% will be best for compatibility probably but check edit of question